# VDI Calculator- design of VDI infrastructure

Tags: performance, vmware, sizing, vdi

Can You Help me?
How much resources are needed for a VMware VDI project  for 800 Users ?

CPU, Memory, Storage or Local Disk?

How many are needed Host's , vCenter Server and Connection Servers?
Please help me in the design of infrastructure?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Description is very vague, but ballpark you should be aware of the following things:

- number of desktops in cluster (in your case 800)
- OS types of the desktops (Windows XP, Vista, 7, etc) as it will affect the number of base images for your [**Linked Clones Pool**](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_clone_overview.html) and amount of resources you need per VM
- OS applications list and types of users(Basic or Power User), it significantly affects number of resources you need, especially  `I/O` capacity of your storage subsystem.
- current performance of physical desktops; I really liked **[VMware Capacity Planner](https://www.vmware.com/products/capacity-planner/overview)**, which can give you really good insights about current performance situation

After you answer these questions, it **highly recommended** to get familiar with following documents:

- [**VMware View Storage Considerations**](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/techpaper/view_storage_considerations.pdf) - based on estimated `I/O` you will be able to plan storage system capacity.
- [**VMware Horizon View Best Practices**](https://www.vmguru.com/2009/12/vmware-view-sizing-best-practices/)
- [**VMware View Backup Best Practices**](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/techpaper/VMware-View-Backup-Best-Practices.pdf)
- [**`"boot storm"`**](http://www.zdnet.com/article/boot-storms-and-how-to-avoid-them/) and [**`"antivirus storm"`**](http://vmturbo.com/blog/controlling-antivirus-storms/) and how to avoid it

To sum up, it's just the initial things I would consider before planning.